# Is it possible to use notifies statement by having a service declared in another recipe, in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

eg.

The directory structure of the recipes is as follows:

`--my_cookbook
  |-- recipes
     |- abc.rb
     |- xyz.rb
  |-- attributes
  |-- templates
     |- random.xml.erb
  |-- test`

Now let's assume we have a resource as follows in `abc.rb`

`... # Line 20
template '/some_location/random.xml' do
    source 'random.xml.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0644'
    notifies :start, 'service[vicious_service]', :immediately
end
... # Line 28`

Now we have the declaration of `vicious_service` which is as follows:

`service 'vicious_service' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end`

The question now is, Can we have the declaration of vicious_service somewhere in `xyz.rb` ? Or is it mandatory for us to declare it in `abc.rb` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what recipe things are in doesn't matter to Chef beyond the original loading phase. Everything ends up in a big array called the "resource collection". You can find more details at https://coderanger.net/two-pass/.